# Xamarin Master Detail project template

Tags: azure, authentication, xamarin

I’m trying to learn to use Xamarin using VS2017 “Master Detail Project template” with Host in Cloud (Azure).

I already had Azure account and fill in the everything at the beginning of the Project template to connect to Azure with my project.
I can’t quite get Authentication and Authorization working.

I have follow this link to configure Google Login 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-how-to-configure-google-authentication
and have the pasted Google Client ID and Client Secret back to Azure portal and have turn Authentication On.

But when I run the app, I can’t get to Google login page.

Question, do I need to do in anything in the client app to get the Authentication and Authorization working?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, it seems you have configured App Service Authentication / Authorization. I would recommend you accessing `https://<your-app-name>.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/google` via the browser to check whether your easy auth could work as expected.

For authentication in Xamarion.Forms project, you could refer to [Xamarin.Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-xamarin-forms-get-started-users#add-authentication-to-the-portable-class-library). Also, you could refer to [Xamarin.Android](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-xamarin-android-get-started-users) and [Xamarin.iOS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-xamarin-ios-get-started-users) for adding authentication to your xamarin app.